# limit of $ x/\sin(\pi x)$ as $x$ approaches zero?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I reorganized as $x\csc(\pi x)$ and input $0$, which would be $0$, but the answer is apparently wrong? It says the answer is $1/\pi$. Any help?

Comment: $\csc(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: You can't "input zero" because $\csc0$ is undefined. Rather, use the fact that $x/\sin x$ tends to 1. (Hint: $x/\sin(\pi x)$ is $1/\pi$ times $\pi x/\sin(\pi x)$.)

Comment: Hint: $$\lim_{\text{a certain number} \to 0}\frac{\sin(\text{that same number})}{\text{that very same number again}} = 1$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{x}{\sin(\pi x)} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\cdot \dfrac{\pi x}{\sin(\pi x)}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show L'Hopital's Rule applies and write

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}  \frac{x}{\sin(\pi x)}=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}  \frac{1}{\pi\cos(\pi x)}$$

Kf-Sansoo's answer provides much more insight, but L'Hopital is a powerful technique for limit calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Recall from geometry, we have the inequalities

$$|\theta\cos(\theta)|\le |\sin(\theta)|\le |\theta| \tag 1$$

for $|\theta|\le \pi/2$.

Letting $\theta=\pi x$ in $(1)$ and dividing by $|x|$ reveals for $0<|x|\le 1/2$

$$\pi \cos(\pi x)\le \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\le \pi $$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\pi$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete.  Please advise.  -Mark